# Get array from JSON in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, json

I wanted to load in map information using JSON, is there a way to get String, Int, float etc lists or arrays from JSON in Libgdx?

My structure looks like this

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "startmap",
        "actors": [{
            "name": "ryder"
        }]
    }]
}
```

And I want to get Actors as either a String List or Array, but there is no GetList or GetArray function. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
First I add a JsonValue to my map object.
Then I add a String list to my map object as well.
JsonValue has this handy method called Child, wich allows me to loop through every child in the JsonValue, wich I add to my list of Strings.

The code looks like this.

```
newMap.actorstorage = saveJson.get("actors");
    for (JsonValue actor = newMap.actorstorage.child; actor != null; actor = actor.next){
        for(int c = 0; c < actor.size; c++){
            newMap.actors.add(actor.getString(c));
    }
}
```

Wich returns something like this

```
[name1,name2]
```